# GooGle PubSub: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were sent out of order

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Receiving following error while consuming messages from PubSub. Message ordering and enableExactlyOnceDelivery are enabled for my subscription. The problem is that once this error occur it seems like PubSub just starts to resend messages constantly, even when they are acknowledged:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were sent out of order.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:92) ~[gax-2.31.1.jar:2.31.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:98) ~[gax-grpc-2.31.1.jar:2.31.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66) ~[gax-grpc-2.31.1.jar:2.31.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-2.31.1.jar:2.31.1]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84) ~[api-common-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1055) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:807) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:578) ~[grpc-stub-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:548) ~[grpc-stub-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:541) ~[gax-grpc-2.31.1.jar:2.31.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.56.1.jar:1.56.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were sent out of order.
```

Did not find any useful information in Google Documentation.

Comment: What version of the client library are you using?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn It's `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub`.

Comment: These are the the properties configured for the library: 
`cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        subscriber:
          executor-threads: 1
          min-duration-per-ack-extension: 60
          max-duration-per-ack-extension: 600`

Comment: But which version of that library? And which version of google-cloud-pubsub are you pulling in?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn The version is `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:4.8.3` , `com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:4.8.3` . Don't use google-cloud-pubsub.